# Plotting Piecewise function, ExclusionsStyle not shown completely

Tags: plotting

Suppose I define

```
f[x] := Piecewise[{{1.7*10^-6, 150 <= x <= 200}}, 0]
```

and then plot

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
     ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

I get an interrupted dashed vertical line on left

[image: Plot of Piecewise function with Exclusion dashed line missing]

Anyone know why this happens and how to draw the entire dashed line?

Comment: Just increase your `PlotPoints` e.g. `PlotPoints->100`.

Comment: Very trivial to worth an answer. If you want just upvote the comment instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematica*'s plot algorithms are not optimized when values become very large or in your case very small. You could include your plot in a `Manipulate` to see the behavior when you adjust e.g. `PlotPoints`

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1.7*10^-6, 150 <= x <= 200}}, 0];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[g[x]], {x, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, PlotPoints -> n, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> All],
 {n, 20, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

And now you could replace your function `f` with an equivalent function `g` which returns 1 and not the very small number. Then you'll see the the plot behaves much better with different settings for `PlotPoints`

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 150 <= x <= 200}}, 0]
```